# Bug in Java Common Element Searcher

Tags: java, arrays

This is **not** a duplicate question - I do not want to use `pre-defined methods`, and instead would like to implement my own basic ***O(n^2)*** algorithm for finding the common elements within 2 lists. My program loops through 2 `arrays`, and compares each element from the first `array` to all the elements from the second `array`. This is all working fine, except for the fact that somehow at the end the program always prints a "0". Why is this? There are no 0s in my `arrays`.

```
public class ArraySameCase {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] firstArray = new int[5];
        firstArray[0] = 1;
        firstArray[1] = 2;
        firstArray[2] = 7;
        firstArray[3] = 9;
        int[] secondArray = new int[5];
        secondArray[0] = 8;
        secondArray[1] = 7;
        secondArray[2] = 1;
        secondArray[3] = 3;
        for(int i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
            for(int y=0; y<secondArray.length; y++){
                if(firstArray[i] == secondArray[y]){
                    System.out.println(firstArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1
> 7
> 0

Comment: BTW You can easily implement an O(N log N) or even O(N) algorithm.

Comment: I suggest you use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArray))` to see it's contents or use your debugger.

Comment: @PeterLawrey How is O(N) possible? Do you mean using HashSet<>?

Comment: @DenisKulagin In this case BitSet would be better but for a larger range HashSet would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the arrays with the lengt of 5 but you only add 4 values. So  `firstArray[4]` and `secondArray[4]` is 0.

Answer (score 4):

You have arrays of size 5 and intitalize only first four elements. 5th is 0 by default.

Use following code to print your arrays to console:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] firstArray = new int[5];
        firstArray[0] = 1;
        firstArray[1] = 2;
        firstArray[2] = 7;
        firstArray[3] = 9;

        int[] secondArray = new int[5];
        secondArray[0] = 8;
        secondArray[1] = 7;
        secondArray[2] = 1;
        secondArray[3] = 3;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call System.out.println(firstArray), won't that call the array's toString method?